# Generate a triple DES key in a file, and use it to encrypt a message

Tags: encryption, command-line, openssl, des

I'm learning cryptography, and I want to use the OpenSSL command line to generate a triple DES key coded in base64 and save the resulting key to a text file, then I want to encrypt a text message using this key file.

I used the standard command "rand" to generate a random value of size 24 bytes coded in base64 and saved it as a key in a text file, but I don't know how to use this file to encrypt a text message using the command "enc", and I'm wondering if there is a better way to generate a triple DES key using OpenSSL command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This isn't a programming or development question, and not really ontopic for SO. It would fit better on security.SX or maybe superuser.
2. If this were (or is) anything oher than a throwaway test, saving a key in clear in a file is probably going to be insecure. That part *really* belongs on security.SX.
3. Technically a triple-DES key (like a single-DES key in the years before it was obsolete) should have the low bit of each octet (on modern systems, byte) set for odd parity. In the '70s when DES was developed and usually implemented in specialized hardware using discrete transistors, this was a very important feature. For the last few decades, and especially for software, these parity bits are usually ignored. For OpenSSL in particular, libcrypto ignores them by default (although there is an option to set or check) and commandline `enc` uses the libcrypto default.
4. Commandine `enc` defaults to password-based encryption which *derives* the key from a supplied password, but can take the actual key with `-K` (uppercase) IN HEX; see the man page.

On Unix this would make it easy if you use `rand -hex` instead:

```
    openssl rand -hex 24 >key.hex
    openssl enc -des-ede3-cbc -K $(cat key.hex) -iv 0123456789ABCDEF -in X -out Y
    # see below
```

On Windows this is also manageable but not as easy; you need something like

```
    openssl rand -hex 24 >key.hex
    for /f %t in ('type key.hex') do set k=%t
    rem double the % if used in a batch file
    openssl enc -des-ede3-cbc -K %k% -iv 0123456789ABCDEF -in X -out Y 
    rem ditto
```

If you insist on base64, you'll need a helper program on Unix

```
    openssl rand -base64 24 >key.b64
    K=$( openssl base64 -d <key.b64 | xxd -p )
    openssl enc -des-ede3-cbc -K $K ... # as above
```

and I don't think it can be done on Windows at all.

Note the IV should be different for each encryption, not hardcoded as in my example, and for CBC in particular it should also be unpredictable by an adversary; this is often most easily done by making it random. Although if it's not CBC mode only loses security to an active attacker while if it repeats at all other modes like CTR and OFB lose security even to a passive attacker. This part belongs on security.SX or crypto.SX where there are already dozens if not hundreds of Qs about it.